# How to run list comprehensions on GPU?

Tags: numpy, performance, gpu

Is there a way to run complex list comprehensions like the following on GPU?

```
[[x[index] if x[index]>len(x) else x[index]-1 for x in slice] if (len(slice)==1) else slice for slice,index in zip(slices,indices)]
```

To what degree is it Possible? Do I have to convert it to some kind of numpy comprehension (if so what part is speciffically possible/necessary)

The goal is performance optimization on large datalists/arrays.

Comment: I think you would get a better response for this on StackOverflow,

Comment: Take a look at Nvidia's Copperhead.